# Page title incorrect on stash paginated results

Tags: stash, switchee

I'm using Stash and Switchee to build some paginated News entries. However, when I click through to Page 2 and beyond, my page title changes to the latest entry in the CMS. Wondered if anyone had a solution for this?

As you can see from the code below, I have a news index page - which I have created as a Page in the CMS at mydomain.tld/news and then within this same template I'm also building up some paginated results rows of news articles. I set a title value for the index page which works fine (this then gets pulled through to the embedded _layouts/index page with the tag {exp:stash:get name="title"}.

Content of _layouts/index;

```
<body id="page mobile-view" class="off-canvas hide-extras {exp:stash:get name='body_class'}">

<div id="size"></div>

<div class="container">

<h1>{exp:stash:get name="page_title"}</h1>

{exp:stash:get name="content"}

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Content of news/index;

```
{embed="_layouts/index"}
{preload_replace:channel="news"}

{exp:switchee variable="{segment_2}" parse="inward"}

    {!-- News index --}
    {case value="#^P(\d+)$#|''"}

        {exp:channel:entries
            channel="page"
            status="open"
            limit="1"
            {global:channel_disable_most}
        }

            {exp:stash:set name="page_title"}{title}{/exp:stash:set}

        {/exp:channel:entries}

        {exp:stash:set parse_tags="yes" parse_conditionals="yes"}

            {stash:results_rows}
                {exp:channel:entries
                    channel="{channel}"
                    orderby="date"
                    sort="desc"
                    limit="6"
                    dynamic="no"
                    status="not closed"
                    paginate="bottom"
                }

                    <div class="twelve columns other_news">
                        <div class="three columns">
                            <a href="{site_url}news/{url_title}" title="{title}">
                                {exp:ce_img:pair
                                    src="{news_leaderimage}"
                                    height="218"
                                    width="380"
                                    attributes='style="width:100%;"'
                                }
                                    <img src="{made}" alt="{title}" />
                                {/exp:ce_img:pair}
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="nine columns">
                            <div class="sub-padding3a">
                                <h1 class="title4"><a href="{site_url}news/{url_title}">{title}</a></h1>
                                <p class="paragraph1 date">Added <span>{entry_date format="{global:date_short}"}</span></p>
                                <div class="paragraph1">
                                    <p>{news_summary} <a class="oLink" href="{site_url}news/{url_title}" title="Read More about {title}">&#0187; Read More</a></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    {stash:absolute_results}{absolute_results}{/stash:absolute_results}

                    {paginate}
                        {stash:pagination_summary}
                            <div style="width:30%; float:left;">
                                Page {current_page} of {total_pages}
                            </div>
                        {/stash:pagination_summary} 
                        {stash:pagination_links}
                            {pagination_links}
                                <div class="refit">
                                    <div class="refit-inner">
                                        {previous_page}<a href="{pagination_url}"><strong>&laquo; Previous</strong></a>{/previous_page}

                                        <div class="push">
                                            {page}<a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-{pagination_page_number} {if current_page}selected{/if}">{pagination_page_number}</a>{/page}
                                            {next_page}<a href="{pagination_url}"><strong>Next &raquo;</strong></a>{/next_page}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            {/pagination_links}
                        {/stash:pagination_links}
                    {/paginate}
                    {stash:all_items}{absolute_results}{/stash:all_items}
                    {if count == 1}{stash:first_item}{absolute_count}{/stash:first_item}{/if}
                    {if count == total_results}{stash:last_item}{absolute_count}{/stash:last_item}{/if}
                {/exp:channel:entries}
            {/stash:results_rows}

        {/exp:stash:set}

        {exp:stash:set name="content"}

            {exp:stash:get name="results_rows"}
            {exp:stash:get name="pagination_summary"}
            {exp:stash:get name="pagination_links"}

        {/exp:stash:set}

    {/case}

{/exp:switchee}
```

Look forward to any helping fixing this bug.

Thank you. :)

Comment: And what's in **_layouts/index**?

Comment: Updated to add the markup from _layouts/index :)

Comment: What if you changed the stash variable to something like `page_title`? Might be some variable collision going on here.

Comment: Can't spot the underlying problem right now but I've noticed a problem with the way you capture the `{title}`. Never use `{exp:stash:set_value value="..."}` to capture a variable that might contain quotes, as a page title might - these can break the EE parser when *passed in a parameter*. Use the tag pair `{exp:stash:set name="title"}{title}{/exp:stash:set}` instead.

Comment: Another problem, you've got an extra double quote in the case value: `{case value="#^P(\d+)$#|"""}`. That should be a pair of single quotes: `{case value="#^P(\d+)$#|''"}`

Comment: Hey Derek and Mark. I've updated templates with your fixes/suggestions and updated the code above to reflect this. Seems to still pull in the latest entry title on the paginated pages though. /testimonials is fine, but /testimonials/P1 etc gets the latest CMS entry title. :/

Comment: I can't see anywhere in your code above where you set a variable called 'title', which is what you are trying to access in the view template. Should you be accessing 'page_title' instead?

Comment: Hey Mark, Sorry forgot to update the embedded template as well after Derek's suggestion that there might be a variable collision. Updated now.

Comment: You still need dynamic="no" (see answer below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have to hard-code the `entry_id` for your `news` entry in the `pages` channel:

```
{exp:channel:entries
  channel="page"
  status="open"
  entry_id="5"
  dynamic="no"
  limit="1"
  {global:channel_disable_most}
 }
```

Or perhaps hard-code the URL title, either directly or with `{segment_1}` (assuming the URL title for the page entry is `news`:

```
{exp:channel:entries
  channel="page"
  status="open"
  url_title="{segment_1}"
  dynamic="no"
  limit="1"
  {global:channel_disable_most}
 }
```

What's happening is that when you leave the index and are on a paginated page (like `/news/P5`), the URL no longer *exactly* matches your index page's **Pages URI** of `/news`. Because there's no exact match, the entries tag does its default behavior and returns the latest entry in EE.

Answer (score 1):

In your example when segment_2 is empty or P1, P2, etc. you are setting the page_title, but that particular channel:entries tag is still dynamic (e.g. no dynamic="no" parameter). If there is no entry with a P2 title, that channel:entries tag will fall back to showing a list of entries instead, which you just limit to 1.

The solution is to also set dynamic=no for the P1 and empty segment. However a better solution is to organize your switchee a bit to catch more clear cases.